# What does this syntax mean: `function (YOLO) ....`

Tags: julia

What does the code mean, and how to invoke it?

```
function (YOLO)
    YOLO + 1
end
```

Quoted from [here](https://miguelraz.github.io/blog/juliawats/).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [Anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions).

The usual way to use them is to either assign it to a variable, which would become the function's name:

```
julia> y = function (YOLO)
           YOLO + 1
       end
#43 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y(4)
5
```

or pass the function itself directly as an argument to a different function (though for that, the shorter `YOLO -> YOLO + 1` or the `do ... end` syntaxes are usually used).

Another way to invoke it is to just immediately call it:

```
julia> (function (YOLO)
           YOLO + 1
       end)(43)
44
```